# Check a condition every 3 minutes without functions and without interrupting the loop

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have this working code that checks a conditions every 3 minutes considering the local time, so every 0, 3, 6, 9.....It prints "checking condition".

```
import time
def get_next_time():
    minute = time.localtime().tm_min
    result = 3 - (minute % 3) + minute
    if result == 60:
         result = 0
    return result

next_run = get_next_time()

while True:

   now = time.localtime()

   if next_run == now.tm_min:
       print("checking condition")
       #some condition

       next_run = get_next_time()
   time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is that I need the code without functions, so I need to find a way to write this code without using any funcion, and I cannot use break or interrput the loop

I tried:

```
while True:

   minute = time.localtime().tm_min
   result = 3 - (minute % 3) + minute
   if result == 60:
       result = 0


   now = time.localtime()
   if result == now.tm_min:
       print("checking conditions")

   time.sleep(1)
```

But it does not work: it does not do nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: `localtime` is a function !

Comment: yes sorry, i mean, without the function 'get_next_time()'

Comment: There are several problems with your code, the most severe being a "busy waiting" loop. Another issue is that if the condition `result == now.tm_min` becomes true, it will remain so for a whole minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compact the function in one statement:

```
import time

next_run = (3 - (time.localtime().tm_min % 3) + time.localtime().tm_min)%60

while True:
    now = time.localtime()

    if next_run == now.tm_min:
        print("checking condition")
        #checking conditions...

        next_run=(3 - (time.localtime().tm_min % 3) + time.localtime().tm_min)%60
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Where is the sleep gone ?

Comment: my bad, fix that in a second.

Comment: In case that the last call to `localtime` occurs on the next minute (this is unlikely but possible), the delay will be 4 minutes instead of 3.

Comment: Mh, and the sleep is outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first time, the `get_next_time()` will only be executed when `next_run == now.tm_min`. The second time, you execute it each loop

```
import time

minute = time.localtime().tm_min
result = 3 - (minute % 3) + minute
if result == 60:
    result = 0

while True:

   now = time.localtime()
   if result == now.tm_min:
       print("checking conditions")
       minute = time.localtime().tm_min
       result = 3 - (minute % 3) + minute
       if result == 60:
           result = 0

   time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding to the next multiple of 3 minutes contradicts the specification "every 0...".

It is enough to do

```
import time

first= True       
while True:
    minute= time.localtime().tm_min
    if first or minute == target:
        print("checking condition")
        first= False
        target= (minute + 3) % 60
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

**Update:**

I modified the code so that a single call to `localtime` is made on every iteration, to make fully sure that the minutes do not change between the calls.

More compact but less efficient:

```
import time

while True:
    minute= time.localtime().tm_min
    if 'target' not in locals() or minute == target:
        print("checking condition")
        target= (minute + 3) % 60
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this way doesn't it check the condition immedately, the first run? Without waiting 0,3,6,9...minute?

Comment: @PrenVen: what difference between waiting zero minute and immediately ???

Comment: with 0 minute i mean (for example) 12:00 time, 13:00, 14:00...not "immediately"

Comment: @PrenVen: I see, this was ambiguous. It invalidates my answer.

Comment: yes sorry, i thought it were comphrensible considering the code I posted, other time i'll be more clear, btw thanks for your effort, your code could always be useful to someone else!